# Create Users Manually - FOSWiki 2.1.2

Tags: foswiki

Just a newbie here on FOSWiki. I recently deployed FOSWiki for our company's internal use.

It is uploaded online, and I have disabled User Registration so only admin can add users after validated that they are from the same company.
So the problem is, how to manually add user accounts to the system?

The user registration page is disabled, so that not everyone on the web can use the company's wiki.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is currently no way to add users without a registration in a sensible way (you could theoretically edit the backend storage, but this is a terrible idea).

You should reenable the user registration using the option `{Register}{EnableNewUserRegistration}`, then activate the administrative approval of new wiki users using the option `{Register}{NeedApproval}`.

Since you are using Foswiki in a company, you might want to use your directory as a user backend, using [LdapContrib](https://github.com/foswiki/LdapContrib) or [LdapContrib (fork of the Contrib)](https://github.com/modell-aachen/LdapContrib). Full disclosure: I am a contributer to the latter version.